# how to handle alerts in android using appium

Tags: android, alert, appium

How do I handle alerts in an Android web application using Appium server (1.0.1) and the Android SDK?

The below code is not working on android:

```
driver.switchTo().accept().alert();
```

Error message:

```
> -modal window does not get closed
```

Comment: Can you post more detail of the error?

Comment: SwitchTo() doesn't work for Appium.

Answer (score 4):

**You need to get the Alert before you try and accept it**

This is code from some of the [Appium Java Client Tests](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/7772a4c4b8760982b0f9ded4585b4a4c1fa87cba/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/iOSGestureTest.java#L74):

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

This should work most of the time.

If `accept()` isn't working, replace the `driver.switchTo().alert();` and `alert.accept();` with code to find the button and then click it.

If it's not finding the button wrap `findElementBy(Method)` code in a try/retry block, and *then* click on it.

Comment: this code will only make driver switch to alert but it won't accept it

Comment: Updated my answer with some more workarounds/solutions you could try. If neither of those work, please paste your Appium server logs

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use the appium inspector. Click on the element and copy the **resource-id** from it. Use this resource id in **findElement(By.id())** method.

> For me resource-id: android:id/button1

```
((AndroidDriver) driver).findElement(By.id("android:id/button1")).click();
```

This is for Android. For regular use you can use

```
driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/button1")).click();
```

Comment: Appium doesn't seem to recognize the system alerts like normal elements. Did your code work?

Answer (score 1):

Some alerts may be **native Android's alerts**, not generated by a browser. In this case the following code:

`Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept();`

may throw:
`WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"No JavaScript dialog to handle"}`

To handle such alert, just switch to the native application context, make required actions, and then switch back to the browser:

```
AppiumDriver<WebElement> appiumDriver = (AppiumDriver<WebElement>) webDriver;
String currentContext = appiumDriver.getContext();
appiumDriver.context("NATIVE_APP");

// actions within the alert
appiumDriver.findElements(By.xpath(OK_BUTTON_LOCATOR)).click(); // put locator instead of OK_BUTTON_LOCATOR
appiumDriver.context(currentContext);

// continue working
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='OK']"));
TouchAction act = new TouchAction(driver);
act.tap(241,320).perform();
```

(241,320) these are X & Y c ordinates of alert 
This work perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Appium comes with a default capability to accept, dismiss alerts

```
capabilities.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
capabilities.SetCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);
```

Comment: Can you tell me the syntax in ruby to set it to true?

Comment: Be advised - Utilizing these capabilities will result in Appium auto-accepting or dismissing the alerts.

Answer (score 0):

If the alert display on Ui , taking more time to display when we need to wait ..we can use fluent wait instead of this..

Answer (score 0):

So an updated answer on this is this: an AlertDialog is a system level element, so clicking on accept button you should use:

```
androidDriver.findElementById("android:id/button1").click()
```

else for cancel do this:

```
androidDriver.findElementById("android:id/button2").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

// first check alert is present or not

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
        mobDriver.switchTo().alert();
        log.info("ALERT IS PRESENT !! ");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("ALERT IS NOT PRESENT !! ");
        return false;
    }
}

public void mobileAlertHandle() {
    if (isAlertPresent()) {
        Alert alert = mobDriver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
   }
}
```

if this does not work then inspect your element and try with id or name

ex: mobDriver.findElementById("android:id/button2").click()

Answer (score -1):

**Please use the below code, Add some wait before clicking on OK Button. 
    After that pass the xpath of you OK Button.**

```
synchronized (driver)
{
driver.wait(2000);
}
driver.context(NATIVE_APP);
driver.findElementByXPath{("//android.widget.Button[@resourceid=
‘android:id/button1’]").click();
```

Comment: **Why** is `wait()` required here? Don't just post a code, add an explanation why it works.