# Appium How To Handle Native Dialog Boxes While Automating Browser

Tags: appium

I am automating dropbox app on mobile chrome browser.There are some actions like upload and download opens up some native dialog boxes.I am not able to automate these native dialog boxes.

Comment: Refer to my answer here :
[This will answer how to handle the native alert dialog box in Android ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41029436/6731329)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

or

```
    driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```