# not able to click on button after the pop-up appears in appium

Tags: java, android, appium, python-appium

I have used appium 1.6.4 and android version is on 5.1 ,6.1 and 7.0

[image]

Below is my code

public boolean navigateToLoginPage(){

```
    String strng = null;
    newObj = new LogInPage();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(GetStarted));
    GetStarted.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    if(Country.isDisplayed()){
        Country.click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Cancel));
        Cancel.click();
    } 
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    MobileNumber.sendKeys("91**********");

    Next.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    OK.click();// this is the problem , this sometimes works sometimes not
```

//i have used the alert interface but no use

//if(OK.isEnabled()){OK.click();} it returns true and I have also used .isDisplayed but no use

//When Ok button is not clicked  but the code in the try block is executed 
//I have also used the tap functionality but no effect

```
        try {
            strng =newObj.try1();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(EnterOTP));
    EnterOTP.sendKeys(strng);
    Next.click();
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635354/how-to-handle-alerts-in-android-using-appium/24641164#24641164

Comment: What does your page object look like?  Also, implicit waits are generally set once, upon instantiation of the driver, then left alone.  Implicit waits should probably be a bit longer, 10-30 seconds, Appium can be slow sometimes.  If you setup your page objects correctly, you should not need anything but the initial implicit wait.  If you have to do waits elsewhere they should be explicit waits.  I'm curious how the page object is initialized, as you don't pass the driver.

Comment: i am using the page Factory and my page elements looks like this



 @FindBy(xpath ="//android.widget.LinearLayout[@text='Mobile']")
 WebElement MobileNumber;
 

 @FindBy(xpath ="//android.widget.Button[@text='Next']")
 WebElement Next;
 

 @FindBy(id ="com.edmobilelabs.sling.dev:id/btnPositive")
 WebElement OK;
  

and in my base class i have instantiated android driver
and all my test class extends my base class
so driver issue is resolved and moreover I am passing the parameters by TestNG so no need to depend upon other class

Comment: @IvanPronin

I have tried your code for switching the contexts , it worked for 2 time but again 3rd time it fails 
Here are my logs : 
{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.edmobilelabs.sling.dev:id/btnPositive","context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.edmobilelabs.sling.dev:id/btnPositive' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
//this is the required id

Comment: @IvanPronin



I have checked the page source and found out that whenever the x & y co-ordinates or the bounds for the button  are bounds="[323,639][516,680]"  


there is success and  

whenver it is  bounds="[352,486][674,598]" button is not clicked 

and for my success bound should be always in between  "[352,486][674,598]" 

and when I check my logs on the appium server 

 when elementId is  5 there is success and when its not vice-versa

Could you guys please suggest how can I over-come this issue ??

Comment: @abishek kachroo, could you please update your question with the latest info: post whole code of finding elements and working with them with the results (fail / success)

Comment: @IvanPronin
I have created the whole new question as I was unable to edit this one or I didn't have the rights,  

here  is   the  link  for the   new   one   :-     

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635657/unable-to-click-on-native-app-generated-pop-up-questions-is-i-am-able-to-click

Comment: Ok, will take a look