# Android popupwindow not seen by Appium

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I have a native android app with a few popup windows that I am trying to create automated tests for using Webdriverio and Appium. I tried interacting with the elements in the popups with varies selectors (Id, class etc) but it seems Appium can't find them.

When I use the inspector in Appium desktop it doesn't see the elements but they do show up in the screenshot it displays. I then tried getting the xml directly from Appium with http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/session/session-id/source and the xml I got back does't have the popup either.

I looked in the appium form and found a few similar questions but no answers that worked.

How do I get appium to see the popup?

**edit:** When using the Android Studio Layout Inspector on an app with an open popup it let's you select from two windows one is the app and one is the popupwindow. I can't figure out how to do this via appium but it could be a lead

Comment: I think there was a workaround that allows you to detect popup elements if you minimise your app and restore it. Let me know if that worked :)

Comment: @Angusiasty Thanks for answering. I tried it but the popups close as soon as I minimize the app so this workaround doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are out of luck.

[This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37017411) is known to be there for years and google doesn't seem to care.

As a workaround in one of my project I kept a list of all possible values in dropdown and selected them by pressing arrow keys and enter.

```
mobileDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.DPAD_DOWN));
mobileDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a few popups with values that are generated at run time so I can't keep a list of all of there possible values. I also have a few popups that can't be accessed via the arrow keys and enter method. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I meant their not there

Comment: If you're unable to use dpad you can only click by coordinates. This will make your tests hard to maintain. As for the list of elements if you won't have one you can: change app implementation, decide this part of the app is not testable, create and API that will give you the values.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to see which of those options to go with unless I figure out the Android Studio Layout Inspector thing

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that activating the [`enableMultiWindows`](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver/blob/ccad8369565907e646cce1406ea6dbb040142ec6/README.md#settings-api:%7E:text=one%20to%20apply.-,enableMultiWindows,-boolean) setting in the **UIAutomator2 driver** can solve the issue of accessing `PopupWindow` elements, such as the `AutoCompleteTextView` dropdown.

To activate the setting in your tests use the [driver API](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/settings/update-settings/index.html) as follows:

```kotlin
val yourDriver = AndroidDriver(URL("..."), UiAutomator2Options())
yourDriver.setSetting("enableMultiWindows", true)
```

---

In the Appium Inspector, you can activate the setting via the [Desired Capabilities](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#update-settings):

```json
"appium:settings[enableMultiWindows]": true
```

([Appium Inspector UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbjtK.png))

Answer (score 0):

First of all that popup in android developmant is called 'Toast'.(short messages)

```
MobileElement toast = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast[1]"));
System.out.println(toast.getText());
```

selector is right for a 100%. You can use that or just "//android.widget.Toast".

Answer (score 0):

[Ivan Pronin's Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635354/how-to-handle-alerts-in-android-using-appium) is the only one that's worked for me. I had a similar issue where the PopupWindow class/view was unaccessible directly from my app's context. Switching to the "NATIVE_APP" context (while saving the current context) allowed me to access the elements in that PopupWindow. Then I was able to switch back to my app's context to continue testing my app.

Answer (score 0):

If Still facing this issue.
connect with dev to set the Android popups set to isfocusable(true) and try inspecting again. See if it works.